# How to get requesting UIWebView from inside of NSURLProtocol

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, nsurlprotocol

My app uses subclassing of NSURLProtocol. There are several UIWebViews in the app and for specific algorithm implemented in NSURLProtocol I need to know which one of the UIWebViews sends the request.

My understanding is that object returned by [self client] should be somewhat connected with requesting object. But neither NSURLProtocolClient (that is the protocol implemented by object returned by [self client]) nor underlying object _NSCFURLProtocolBridge have any properties/methods to get the sender of the request.

Can anyone help me with ideas?

Answer (score 3):

`NSURLRequest` has a method called `mainDocumentURL` which returns the URL of the root document. You can possibly save that away in the `UIWebViewDelegate` method like this,

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
   if([[request.URL absoluteString] isEqualToString:[request.mainDocumentURL absoluteString]]) 
   {
      // associate this URL with this UIWebview
   }
}
```

You can then look at the `mainDocumentURL` in your `NSURLProtocol` methods to identify the `UIWebView`. This is not fool proof since it doesn't account for cases where multiple `UIWebViews` load the same URL. But this is the best solution I could think of.

Answer (score 1):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19700910/502149. To summarize, you can set the user agent for each `UIWebView` before you create it using the user defaults. Because the view doesn't take subsequent changes of the user agent into account, you'll end up with a different user agent in each `UIWebView`. You can use this in `NSURLProtcol` to identify the view, and you can pass on the real UA agent so the server won't see any difference.

Note that for the `UIWebView` to "remember" the UA string setting, it has to make at least one request before the setting is changed.

Answer (score 0):

in loadRequest:

```
static NSString* ProtocolClient=@"urAPP_ProtocolClient";

    NSMutableURLRequest* Request=[request mutableCopy];
    [Request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"someID",self.someID] forHTTPHeaderField:ProtocolClient];
```

in protocol:

```
NSString* header=[_currentRequest valueForHTTPHeaderField:ProtocolClient];

if (header) {
```

Comment: I certainly can distinguish requests that I create explicitly. The question was about requests for referenced resources (like images, script files etc) that UIWebView sends itself. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)aWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

Request is mutable type. So you can use
`+[NSURLProtocol setProperty:forKey:inRequest:]` to set custom property.
And `+[NSURLProtocol propertyForKey:inRequest]` from inside of `NSURLProtocol`

Answer (score -1):

Ideally, you shouldn't have to reference the UIWebView directly from the NSURLProtocol.  However, I have had need in the past to have an NSURLProtocol send messages to UIWebView that are outside of the regular delegate messages... use NSNotificationCenter, I post notifications using the NSURLRequest object as the object, and subscribe to those notifications on my interested listener.