# iOS: passing custom NSURL to NSURLProtocol

Tags: ios, nsurl, nsurlrequest, nsurlprotocol

I need to pass some extra informations along with `UIWebView loadRequest:` so that it reaches my implementation of `NSURLProtocol`. The information cannot be bound to `NSURLRequest` because the information must be retained with `NSURLRequest mainDocumentURL` as well. So i subclassed `NSURL` and constructed `NSURLRequest` with it. I already knew that the `NSURLRequest` which reaches `NSURLProtocol startLoading` is NOT the instance i have fed to `UIWebView loadRequest`, so i implemented `NSURL copyWithZone` too, naively expecting that URL loading system will use it.

Now, `NSURLProtocol canInitWithRequest` is called not once as one would reasonably expect, but at least 4 times before `startLoading`. First 2 times of that, the incoming `NSURLRequest` still contains my custom `NSURL` implementation. Then an unfortunate internal code called `CFURLCopyAbsoluteURL` asks for the `absoluteURL` of my custom `NSURL` and the next `canInitWithRequest` (and subsequent `startLoading`) already gets a completely new `NSURLRequest` with fresh `NSURL` in it. `copyWithZone` is never called and my subclassed `NSURL` is lost.

Before i give up and implement an inferior and fragile solution with attaching stuff directly to the URL string, i would like to ask the wizards of higher level, whether they see a way how to catch that initial blink on the `NSURLProtocol` radar or how to trick `CFURLCopyAbsoluteURL` into carrying my custom instance. I have tried to hack `NSURL absoluteURL` by returning again a new instance of my custom NSURL class, but it didn't help. I have seen some promise in [`NSURLProtocol setProperty`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSURLProtocol_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLProtocol/setProperty%3aforKey%3ainRequest%3a) functionality, but now it appears pretty useless. URL loading system creates new instances of everything happily and `NSURLRequest` arrived in `NSURLProtocol` seems to be the same as the one entered into `UIWebView` only accidentally.

**UPDATE:** ok i wanted to keep the post as short as possible, but the even the first reply is asking for technical background, so here we go: i've got multiple `UIWebView`s in app. These views may run requests concurrently and absolutely can run requests for the same URL. It's like tabs in desktop browser. But i need to distinguish which `UIWebView` was the origin of each particular `NSURLRequest` arriving to the `NSURLProtocol`. I need a context being carried with each URL request. I can't simply map the URLs to data, because multiple `UIWebViews` may be loading the same URL at any moment.

**UPDATE 2:** Attaching the context information to `NSURL` is preferred and, as far as my understanding goes, the only usable. The issue is that requests for resources referenced inside page (images etc.) do not go through `UIWebViewDelegate` at all and end up in `NSURLProtocol` directly. I don't have a chance to touch, inspect or modify such requests anywhere prior to `NSURLProtocol`. The only contextual link for such requests is their `NSURLRequest mainDocumentURL`.

Comment: The key issue here is that you're trying to load more information on an `NSURL` than the URL. So the question is, what kind of information you're trying to pass through? Typically you would side-load this, by storing a map of URLs to "other data" in some object accessible to the `NSURLProtocol`, but I think a better understanding of what you're trying to solve would help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's some way to get your original `NSURL` used as `mainDocumentURL` that would be ideal. If there's no way to prevent it being copied, I thought of the following hack as an alternative:

Before the creation of each `UIWebView`, [set the user agent string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8666438/502149) to a unique value. Supposedly this change only affects `UIWebView` objects that are created subsequently, so each view will end up with its own distinctive user agent string.

In the `NSURLProtocol` implementation, you can check the user agent string to identify the associated `UIWebView` and pass it through to the real protocol handler using the actual user agent string (so the server will see nothing different).

All this depends on the views really ending up with different UA strings. Let me know if you manage to get it to work!

Comment: This works for me, despite depending on at least two undocumented iOS features. Changing **User-Agent** really affects only the newly created `UIWebView`s, not the existing ones. For the record, you need to pass at least one `NSURLRequest` through the newly created `UIWebView` to make the **User-Agent** "stick".

Comment: Pavel, how much data you need to pass through NSURL? If you only need "to distinguish which UIWebView was the origin of each particular NSURLRequest arriving to the NSURLProtocol" you can use setCachePolicy with your own value for your main request. And NSURLProtocol will pass that value for child requests of UIWebView. Anyway you can set cachePolicy to default when you catch it. But I'm not shure that is a good way... What you think?

Answer (score 1):

You say that you can't put it on the `NSURLRequest`, but I'm not clear why from your updated discussion. That would be the most natural place to put it.

- Implement `webView:shouldLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`.
- Attach an extra property to the provided request using `objc_setAssociatedObject`. Then return `YES`. (It would be nice to use `setProperty:forKey:inRequest:` here, but `UIWebView` passes us a non-mutable request, so we can only attach associated objects. Yet another way that `UIWebView` is a pale shadow of OS X's `WebView`, which can handle this).
- In the `NSProtocol`, read your extra property using `objc_getAssociatedObject`. The request should be the same one you were presented earlier. You suggest that this isn't the case. Are you saying that the request at `webView:shouldLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` is different than the request at `initWithRequest:cachedResponse:client:`?

Am I missing another requirement or quirk?

Comment: For the preference of `NSURL` over `NSURLRequest` see **UPDATE2**. I was almost going for `objc_setAssociatedObject` in the very beginning of this pilgrimage, but then i found out that, and i confirm it, that `NSURLProtocol` is consulted with the original object only initially, then handed with completely new instances of both `NSURLRequest` and the enclosed `NSURL`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass options through custom request headers, assuming that the targeted website or service provider don't somehow strip those in transit.

The challenge there would be coming up with an encoding scheme that can be reasonable encoded into an ASCII string for the header field value and then decoded into the actual value you want. For this, a custom `NSValueTransformer` would seem most appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for picking up my email call and sorry for the late reaction. I was off to something else. I ended up using request header, so +1, but not the way you're suggesting. The problem with your solution is that i'm not creating the requests myself, they're sourced in `UIWebView`. As you probably know, the interface mockery called `UIWebViewDelegate` consults just the frame URLs with you. I need to distinguish *all* resource requests.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I finally stuck to the solution suggested by Matthew (using the user agent string). However, as the solution is not fleshed out, I add a new answer with more details. Furthermore, I found out that you do not need to send a request to make the user agent "stick". It is sufficient to get via javascript as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297733/how-to-get-uiwebview-user-agent).

Following steps worked for me:

(1) Get the current default user agent. You need it later to put it back into the request in NSURLProtocol. You need to use a new webview insatnce, as getting the user agent will make it stick to the webview, so you can not change it later on.

```
UIWebView* myWebview = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
NSString* defaultUserAgent = [myWebview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"navigator.userAgent"];
[myWebview release]; // no needed with ARC, but to emphasize, that the webview instance is not needed anymore
```

(2) Change the value in the standardUserDefaults (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478387/change-user-agent-in-uiwebview-iphone-sdk)).

```
NSDictionary* userAgentDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"yourUserAgent", @"UserAgent", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:userAgentDict];
```

(3) Make the new user agent string stick to your webView by getting it via javascript as done in (1), but this time on the webview instance you actually work with.

(4) Revert the default user agent in the standardUserDefaults as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676235/how-can-i-remove-value-that-was-previously-registered-via-nsuserdefaults-regist/18109860#18109860).