# Know what UIViewController make request

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have my `URLProtocol` implementation class.
In my app I have there is more than one `UIViewController` that can do http requests (there is only one visible, but more actives).
There is a way to know what instance of viewcontroller (in my `URLProtocol` implementation) is making the request?

Comment: Just make a method that accepts UIViewController?

Comment: You better to use blocks, to receive callback from your requests, not delegate.

Comment: Why not cut & paste some code that describes how you are generating your http requests and how you are implementing URLProtocol?

Comment: The requests are made by a webview, for requests that I write there is no problem of course, because I know all of those.

Comment: What kind of webview is it?  UIWebView or WKWebView or?

Comment: UIWebView, with WKWebView we can't use URLProtocol

Answer (score 0):

Set your view controller to be a delegate of your UIWebView (if you haven't done it already), then you can do something like this:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSLog(@"url %@", [[request URL] absoluteString]);

    // now you know which view controller made this request
    //
    // you could save this to a property in the view controller
    // or to a table of view controllers/web views 

    return YES;
}
```

I'm basing my answer on what I found [in this very related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367122/how-to-get-requesting-uiwebview-from-inside-of-nsurlprotocol).